# Getting matching text & number in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to be able to get a matching combination from a string. Example:

```
$mystring = "This is my text00123 blah blah";
$code = magicRegex( $mystring, "text"[0-9] );
return "you are a wizard - your code is " . $code;
```

Return:

```
you are a wizard - your code is text00123
```

Then, I need to separate the text from the integers into separate variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another alternative, named catching:

```
\b(?<text>\w+?)(?<number>\d+)\b
```

Demo:

```
$str = "This is my text00123 blah blah";

$_ = null;
preg_match("/\b(?<text>\w+?)(?<number>\d+)\b/",$str,$_);
echo "Text: {$_[text]} -- Number: {$_[number]}";
```

**[Working Demo](http://www.ideone.com/qPtm1)**

*Oops, reversed the arguments. ;p*

Comment: +1 good idea with the named capture groups... simpler than my solution ;)

Comment: @FelixKling: Yea, wouldn't been better if I had the arguments in the right order the first time. D'oh! (And I figured named matches would go a little further for a beginner. :grin:)

Comment: Thanks! Any way to match the actual text "text" - specifically? I can't match just any text-num combo. I should've been clearer about this, sorry.

Comment: @DannyGarcia: It does, check out the demo. Unless you'd like to seclude that as a catch on its own? -- EDIT: You mean it has to be the text `text` as a prefix? replace `(?<text>\w+?)` with `text` in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
preg_match("text[0-9]+", $mystring, $matches);
$code = $matches[0];
```

To split the string you could  use [*lookahead and lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
list($text, $number) = preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/', $code);
```

Comment: Look at you getting fancy, pulling out your [list](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)...

Comment: @Brad Christie: You have your named groups :-P :D ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) to do the job. The right pattern would most likely be `"/(text[0-9]+)/"` assuming you'd like at least 1 number.

Answer (score 0):

for the first one, you can do

```
$code = preg_replace("/.*(text[0-9]*).*/", "$1", $mystring);
```